# R Capturing regression slopes by group in a dataframe

Tags: r, lm, broom

My dataframe consists of scores for different questions asked in a survey, over 3 fiscal years (FY13, FY14 & FY15).
The results are presented by `Region`.

Here's what a **sample** of the actual dataframe looks like, where we have two questions per region, asked in different years.

```
testdf=data.frame(FY=c("FY13","FY14","FY15","FY14","FY15","FY13","FY14","FY15","FY13","FY15","FY13","FY14","FY15","FY13","FY14","FY15"),
              Region=c(rep("AFRICA",5),rep("ASIA",5),rep("AMERICA",6)),
              QST=c(rep("Q2",3),rep("Q5",2),rep("Q2",3),rep("Q5",2),rep("Q2",3),rep("Q5",3)),
              Very.Satisfied=runif(16,min = 0, max=1),
              Total.Very.Satisfied=floor(runif(16,min=10,max=120)))
```

**My Objective**

For each region, my objective is to identify which question experienced the **most significant upward evolution** across this 3 year time frame. In order to measure significant upward movements, I have decided to use the **slope** of regression as a parameter.

The question with the most significant upward evolution within a region over the 3 years time frame will be the one with the **steepest positive slope**.

Using this logic, I have decided to do the following -

1) For each combination of `Region` and `QST`, I run the `lm` function.

2) I extract the slope for each combination, and store it as a separate variable. Then for each region I filter out the question with the maximum slope value.

**My Attempt**

Here is my attempt at solving this.

```
test_final=testdf %>%   
group_by(Region,QST) %>% 
map(~lm(FY ~ Very.Satisfied, data = .)) %>%
map_df(tidy) %>%
filter(term == 'circumference') %>%
select(estimate) %>% 
summarise(Value = max(estimate))
```

> However when I run this I get an error message saying that object `FY`
>   was not found.

**Additional requirement**

Also I'd like this to work only for questions that have at least 2 consecutive years of data for comparison. But I'm unable to figure out how to factor this condition into my code.

Any help with this would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: There are a couple issues here including: First, `FY` is, I assume, supposed to be the fiscal year. But R doesn't know that it is a date, so it is going to think you want to regress a multi-valued factor on a numeric variable. It wont like that. You need to convert FY to numeric values like years. Is this what you intend? Also, if you want the linear approximation to how satisfaction has changed over time you should do the regression the other way around `lm(satisfaction~date)`, is that what you are after?

Comment: Yes that is what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This doesn't do the "at least two consecutive years" part, but it does the "get the question with the largest slope" part:

```
library(dplyr)
test_final = testdf %>%
  mutate(FY.num = as.numeric(gsub("FY", "", FY))) %>%
  group_by(Region, QST) %>%
  mutate(lm_slope = lm(Very.Satisfied ~ FY.num)$coefficients[["FY.num"]]) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  group_by(Region) %>%
  filter(lm_slope == max(lm_slope))
```

Answer (score 3):

Here is a similar version with filtering by group size/contiguity (had written it by the time you posted so figured I might as well go ahead).

```r
library(tidyverse)
set.seed(42)
testdf=data.frame(FY=c("FY13","FY14","FY15","FY14","FY15","FY13","FY14","FY15","FY13","FY15","FY13","FY14","FY15","FY13","FY14","FY15"),
                  Region=c(rep("AFRICA",5),rep("ASIA",5),rep("AMERICA",6)),
                  QST=c(rep("Q2",3),rep("Q5",2),rep("Q2",3),rep("Q5",2),rep("Q2",3),rep("Q5",3)),
                  Very.Satisfied=runif(16,min = 0, max=1),
                  Total.Very.Satisfied=floor(runif(16,min=10,max=120)))

test_final <- testdf %>%   
  group_by(Region,QST) %>% # group by region
  mutate(numdate = as.numeric(str_remove(FY, "FY"))) %>% 
  filter(n() >= 2 & max(diff(numdate)) < 2) %>% # filter out singleton groups
  mutate(slopes = coef(lm(Very.Satisfied~numdate))[2])
test_final %>% select(Region, QST, slopes)
#> # A tibble: 14 x 3
#> # Groups:   Region, QST [5]
#>    Region  QST   slopes
#>    <fct>   <fct>  <dbl>
#>  1 AFRICA  Q2    -0.314
#>  2 AFRICA  Q2    -0.314
#>  3 AFRICA  Q2    -0.314
#>  4 AFRICA  Q5    -0.189
#>  5 AFRICA  Q5    -0.189
#>  6 ASIA    Q2    -0.192
#>  7 ASIA    Q2    -0.192
#>  8 ASIA    Q2    -0.192
#>  9 AMERICA Q2     0.238
#> 10 AMERICA Q2     0.238
#> 11 AMERICA Q2     0.238
#> 12 AMERICA Q5     0.342
#> 13 AMERICA Q5     0.342
#> 14 AMERICA Q5     0.342

test_final %>% group_by(Region) %>% 
  summarise(Value = max(slopes),
            Top_Question = QST[which.max(slopes)])
#> # A tibble: 3 x 3
#>   Region   Value Top_Question
#>   <fct>    <dbl> <fct>       
#> 1 AFRICA  -0.189 Q5          
#> 2 AMERICA  0.342 Q5          
#> 3 ASIA    -0.192 Q2
```

<sup>Created on 2019-01-21 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.1)</sup>

Comment: Much more elegant than mine - very nice!

Comment: @A.S.K. yours is almost identical! and you posted it first, so credit to you

Comment: Thank you both very much. What modification would I need to make to your code to show the top 3 instead of just the max value?